# Car heater not working

Tags: hyundai, heater

My Hyundai Verna/Accent heater is not working. The fan works but it's not blowing any hot air, only cold air.

Any ideas to what might be causing this, if so what parts will need to be replaced/repaired?

Comment: More info about the car would be great. I have an '08 Azera with the auto temp system in it. Pit had the same issue. Turned out to be the motor on the blend door was bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the coolant level?  Possibly the thermostat.  Also could be a plugged heater core or even air trapped in the cooling system.

Answer (score 1):

Could also be failure on heater switch mechanics.

It depends on hot/cool selector type but if it is mechanical then select should never feel loose when turning from cool to hot or the other way round.

If selector is mechanical which means hot/cool valve is operated by some kind of rigid cable or steel rod and it is not uncommon for them to break at cable/rod endpoint joints. Another common symptom could be quiet rattling noise when turning from selector.

Answer (score 0):

Your Hyundai has an auto AirCon system. When the AirCon is turned off the switch for the AirCon opens a valve on the heater inlet to allow hot water into the heater. If the switch or the valve fail then the heater does not receive hot water and blows cold.

You make no mention of overheating or warning lights coming on, so I would assume the cooling system is OK.

The AirCon system can be checked fully with a suitable scanner.